# How to use ampersands in PHP GET URL variable (or function argument)?

Tags: php, function, variables, get, ampersand

I've got the following code (this is WordPress function) (example of wrong structure):

```
<?php paginate_comments_links('prev_text=&#x2190;&nbsp;Older&next_text=Newer&nbsp;&#x2192;'); ?>
```

Example of correct structure:

```
<?php paginate_comments_links('prev_text=Older&next_text=Newer'); ?>
```

As you can see I'm trying to add preceding arrow + space (`&#x2190;&nbsp;`) to 'Older' word and space + arrow (`&nbsp;&#x2192;`) to 'Newer' word. The problem is that there is a conflict between & that separates 2 function arguments and & that is the beginning of HTML character.

How should correct structure look like?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In case someone searches for the same question:

In order to pass a parameter with ampersands (&), you need to encode it.

use `urlencode()`

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

---

To decode it afterward,
use: `urldecode()`

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: urlencode of 'hello&nbsp;world ww' gives 'hello&nbsp;world%20ww' breaking the url parameter.

Comment: encoding & also breaks the url parameter in between, it is not working.