# How to pass "&" as part of an string in PHP?

Tags: php, get

How to pass "&" as part of an String in PHP?

Example:

```
str_test = "john&Sarah"

php_link = "www.test.com?names="+str_test
```

The result of this is:

```
www.test.com?names=John&Sarah
```

But php understand:

```
$GET_Names['names'] = John
```

I need it understand & as part of the name so

```
$GET_Names['names'] = john&Sarah
```

Is there a way to do that without replacing & and re-replacing it again later?

Comment: Use "&amp;" or "%26" ...

Comment: Try searching before posting questions that have been asked before. See solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9489630/3205578

Comment: Don't use `&amp;`, the browser will decode it back to `&` when it converts the HTML to a URI.

Comment: You sound like you've never used php at all. Maybe slow down and get some more basics covered first. For example, you should URL encode any query string before outputting. i'm pretty sure what you have now does nothing and wouldn't work.

Comment: @Anthony - More basic than assigning strings? Not sure where you would go from there ..

Comment: Sorry for not well explaining. I'm constructing the url string from an VB.NET application. I just needed to replace & for %26 as Quentin suggested.

Comment: @webnoob - I would start with proper variable syntax and global variable usage. Maybe also the basics of how query strings work. I don't understand in the OP example why the query string is being built the way it is and then used later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%26` to represent a `&` as data in a URL.

Answer (score 3):

Use existing functions exactly made for this purpose:

```
$str_test = urlencode("john&Sarah");
```

When you submit formdata, the browser automatically does encode the params. When you manually make a HTTP request, you need to manually form the data properly.

Sooner or later you will find out more characters that make your script behave *unexpected*, like a simple blankspace in a HTTP request, or a questionmark.

Comment: Thank you DanFromGermany but I'm not writing the code that generates the "post" variables from the php side. I'm calling a website and passing the variables at the URL. one variable has "&" in the middle of it. Replacing & for %26 worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Dude. "*I'm calling a website and passing the variables at the URL*" This is what other people call "manually doing a HTTP request". You have to `urlencode` the variables....

Answer (score 0):

You seem lost. Here are some valid examples

```
// Assigned a string
$name = "john&Sarah";

// Assigned another string
$name = "john & Sarah";

//Get a name from query parameter
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

You need to be clearer with what you are trying to do, some of your code is invalid / makes no sense.