# Querystring value with a & is disturbing the operations

Tags: php

Iam calling a querystring value which sometimes has an '&' in it. For example :

```
 price_add.php?supplier_name=Devices & Services Co.&tender_id=481
```

In the above example in the supplier_name=Devices & Services (got a & in the supplier_name) and the operation is just taking 'Devices' instead of 'Devices & Services'. How will i solve this problem in php. Iam calling this script in the below format:

```
 <A onclick="window.open('comparitive_files/price_add.php?supplier_name={$supplier_name}&amp;tender_id={$tender_id}','mywindow','width=1200,height=800, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes')" href="#">PRICE</A>
```

Comment: Is Google down? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488953/how-to-use-ampersands-in-php-get-url-variable-or-function-argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escaping ampersand in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript encodeUri() function before setting the URL. For eg.:

```
var url = encodeURI('price_add.php?supplier_name=Devices & Services Co.&tender_id=481');
```

console.info(url);

```
"price_add.php?supplier_name=Devices%20&%20Services%20Co.&tender_id=481"
```